How does it behave to use ReplacementMode.CHARGE_PRORATED_PRICE to upgrade to shorter duration subscription?
Let's say there are subscriptions Tier 1 and Tier 2, each with monthly and yearly basic plans. What is supposed to happen when a user subscribes to the yearly plan of Tier 1 first, and then immediately upgrades to the monthly plan of Tier 2 with ReplacementMode.CHARGE_PRORATED_PRICE mode?
I'm observing on Sandbox that when I try to purchase Tier 2 it shows a higher price than its monthly price, so I guess it is not a monthly price but somehow calculated yearly price. However isn't it weird since I was trying to purchase a monthly subscription?
There's no exact same example in the Android Developers document. I also googled a bit but have no clue as of now, so I'd be glad if someone could lead me. Thank you.
BTW, I found this post in RevenuCat community but there is a reason we are not using WITH_TIME_PRORATION mode.

It seems that upgrading from a yearly subscription to a monthly subscription in the middle is not a general use case in the first place. Most subscription service providers must not allow users to do it. So, should we app developers disable users from doing that?
